# Click link behind clickable element

Tags: css, hyperlink, z-index

I'm making a slideshow (using Slick), where the 'next'-button is simply a 500x500px div covering the whole slide – so you can click anywhere on it in order to get to the next slide.
However, on some of the slides I also want some text links. On similar problems with links 'buried' behind overlaying elements I've seen solutions using `pointer-events:none` on the top layer. This lets me click the link below, however, it also removes the link from the top layer. I've also tried playing around with the `z-index` and `position`, but somehow I can't manage to bring only the link to the surface, without compromising the link covering the rest of the slide.
I guess an example of what I'm looking for is how Twitter handles external links in their tweets – you can click on the tweet itself (expanding it), but also on the link within it.
 How can I click on a link behind a link?

Comment: Please, provide more information(CSS, HTML, jsfiddle and etc)

Comment: You probably don't need to have the 500x500px div covering the whole slide. Just attach a JavaScript click event handler on the container, then look at `event.target` to determine what was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to use a especific DIV to execute the "next slide event", you can use the container click event. Like this:

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#container').click(function(){
                    // Call your next slide.
                    window.redirect = 'http://www.microsoft.com';
                });
                $('#container a').click(function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    return true;
                });
            });
```

HTML example:

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: #f1f1f1" id="container">
            <!-- Here goes your div content -->
            Some text bla bla bla <a href="#">link</a><br><br>
            Some text bla bla bla <a href="#">link</a><br><br>
            Some text bla bla bla <a href="#">link</a><br><br>
        </div>
```

See if this resolve your problem.